# Django signal to recognise which view called

Tags: django

I have a model with two different views.

The problem is that I have a signal registered to the model, and I want to change the behaviour of the signal based on what view called the object save method.

Is there a way doing so?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: no.

Longer answer: well, technically, you *could* inspect the stack, but you really DONT want to go into such kind of  dirty hacks. If you need specific "per view" behaviour, do it in the views (or in functions explicitely called by the views if you need to factor out this behaviour).

Also and FWIW, the point of signals is to allow for decoupling between apps - more specifically, to allow *your* app to hook into *other* apps (3rd part mostly) without having to touch those other apps code. [Having signal handlers for models of your own app is an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/).

Answer (score 0):

Built-in Signals are handled by django itself, so you can only achieve that by passing extra flag to the signal (if you don't want to inspect the caller):

```
def first_view(request):
    #...
    model_instance._through_view = 'first'
    model_instance.save()
    #...

def second_view(request):
    #...
    model_instance._through_view = 'second'
    model_instance.save()
    #...
```

and for your signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def pre_save_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    through_view = getattr(instance, '_through_view' None)

    if through_view == 'first':
        ...
    elif through_view == 'second':
        ...
```

Comment: while your solution is "technically correct", it's a maintenance nightmare waiting the OP if he goes that way. Actually, just using models signals on an app's own models is already an antipattern, as explained in the article I linked to.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes I agree to some degree, but sometimes we just want to _make things working_ :)

Comment: There are other (better) ways, that are not much more complicated to set up, and that will not compromise the project's maintainability. Adding ketchup on spaghetti code doesn't make it easier to clean up, quite on the contrary.